# Getting % of responses for multiple categories in a tibble/df

Tags: r, tidyverse

Using Tidyverse how can I go from a table that has responses for people to if they either consume or not multiple categories like this:

```
TBL
beer wine  soda
yes  yes   yes
yes  yes   yes
yes  no    yes
no   no    yes
no   no    yes
```

To a table that shows responses like this:

```
TBL
cat      yes   no
beer     0.6   0.4
wine     0.4   0.6
soda     1.0   0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
 mutate(num = case_when(value == 'yes' ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)) %>% 
   group_by(name) %>% summarise(yes = sum(num == 1)/n(), no = 1 - yes) %>% 
     select('cat' = name, yes, no)
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  cat     yes    no
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 beer    0.6   0.4
2 soda    1     0  
3 wine    0.4   0.6
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "cat") %>%
  group_by(cat) %>%
  summarise(yes = sum(value == "yes")/n(), 
            no = 1 - yes) 
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  cat     yes    no
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 beer    0.6   0.4
2 soda    1     0  
3 wine    0.4   0.6
```

Comment: Minor simplification - `sum(value == "yes")/n()` can be shortened to `mean(value == "yes")`

Answer (score 2):

Mixing a little base with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyr)
tbl %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "cat") %>%
  table %>%
  prop.table(margin = 1)
#       value
# cat     no yes
#   beer 0.4 0.6
#   soda 0.0 1.0
#   wine 0.6 0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(cat) %>%
  group_by(cat) %>% 
  summarise(yes = mean(value == "yes"),
            no = 1 - yes)


# A tibble: 3 x 3
  cat     yes    no
 <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 beer    0.6   0.4
2 soda    1     0  
3 wine    0.4   0.6
```